# Kendo UI Grid: Dropdown editor opens and immediatly closes when a page is scrolled down to the bottom

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a problem with a Kendo MVC Grid with DropDown editor. When I scroll down the page and try to open the dropdown editor, it opens and immediately closes:
[recorded undesired behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERHui.gif)

Here the Grid itself:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TimeRecordViewModel>()
      .Name("timeGrid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .ServerOperation(true)
          .Batch(false)
          .Aggregates(agg =>
          {
              agg.Add(tr => tr.STime).Sum();
              agg.Add(tr => tr.Penalty).Sum();
          })
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(p => p.Id);
              model.Field(p => p.Penalty).Editable(false);
              model.Field(p => p.User).Editable(User.HasRole(UserRole.CanAssignTimeRecordsToAnotherUser));
              model.Field(p => p.STime).Editable(false);
              model.Field(p => p.Comment).Editable();
              model.Field(p => p.ReportDate).Editable(User.HasRole(UserRole.CanAssignTimeRecordsToAnotherUser));
              model.Field(p => p.Project).Editable();
              model.Field(p => p.Area).Editable();
              model.Field(p => p.WorkItem).Editable();
              model.Field(p => p.AddDate).Editable(false).DefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
          })
          .PageSize(1000000)
          .Read(read => read.Action("TimeRecordsActionResult_Read", "TimeSheet").Data("TimeSheet.getData"))              
          .Update(update => update.Action("TimeRecordActionResult_Update", "TimeSheet"))         
      .Events(e => e.RequestEnd("function (args) { TimeRecords.onRequestEnd(args); KendoUiHelper.requestEnd(args, 'timeGrid', {highlightWholeRowOnError: false, preventDataBound: false, " +
                              "onDataBound: TimeSheet.onDataBound, detailTable: false}); }"))
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' id='chkSelect_#= Id#' onclick='KendoGridBatchEditing.checkBoxSelectRow(this)' userId='#= Id#' />").Width(50).Hidden(true);
          columns.Bound(product => product.ReportDate).Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}").Title("Report Date").Width("6%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.User.NativeNameWithoutPatronymic)
              .Title("User")
              .ClientTemplate("#=User.NativeNameWithoutPatronymic#")
              .EditorTemplateName("UserPicker")
              .Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.Project.ProjectName)
              .Title("Project")
              .EditorTemplateName("ProjectPicker")
              .ClientTemplate("<a href='#=Project.ProjectURL#' target='_blank' class='grid-link'>#=Project.ProjectName#</a>")
              .Width("12%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.Area.Name)
              .Title("Area")
              .ClientTemplate("#= Area.Name #")
              .EditorTemplateName("AreaPicker")
              .Width("12%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.WorkItem.WorkItemName)
              .EditorTemplateName("TaskPicker")
              .Title("Work Item")
              .ClientTemplate("<a href='#= WorkItemUrl#' target='_blank' class='grid-link'>#= WorkItemTitle#</a>")
              .Width("20%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.STime)
              .Title("Hours")
              .ClientFooterTemplate("<span id=\"total-hours\">#=  TimeSheet.calculateResult(sum, 0) #</span>")
              .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= TimeSheet.calculateResult(sum, 1) #")
              .Width("4%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.Comment).Title("Comment").ClientTemplate("#=CommentToShow#").Width("32%");
          columns.Bound(product => product.Penalty)
              .Title("Penalty")
              .ClientFooterTemplate("#= sum #")
              .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= sum #")
              .Width("4%");
      })
      .ToolBar(t =>
      {
          t.Template(@<text>
                         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class='k-button simplebox' id="printGrid" style="float: left;">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>Print
                         </a>
                         <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" style="float: left;">
                             <span class="k-icon k-i-file-excel"></span>Export to Excel
                         </button>
                         @if (User.HasRole(UserRole.CanAssignTimeRecordsToAnotherUser))
                         {
                             <button id="batchEditing" class="k-button simplebox" type="button" onclick="KendoGridBatchEditing.addCheckboxesToGrid(this)">Batch Editor Off</button>
                         }
                         <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                      </text>);
      })
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
      .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
      .Events(e =>
      {
          e.Edit("TimeSheet.onEdit");
          e.Save("TimeSheet.onSave");
          e.DataBound("TimeSheet.onDataBound");
          e.Group("KendoGridBatchEditing.clearSelectedRows");
      })
      .Excel(e =>
      {
          e.FileName("TimeRecordsFull " + DateTime.Today.Date + ".xlsx")
              .Filterable(true)
              .ProxyURL(Url.Action("ExcelExport", "TimeSheet"));
      })
      .Sortable()
      .Groupable()
      .Filterable()
      )
```

And here the DropDown editor

```
jQuery(function () {
    var dropDown = jQuery("#WorkItem").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "WorkItemName",
        dataValueField: "WorkItemID",
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/TimeSheet/GetWorkItemsList",
                    dataType: "json",
                    gridId: "@(ViewBag.gridName ?? "timeGrid")",
                    data: TimeRecordsGridHelper.filterTasks
                }
            }
        },
        dataBound: adjustDropDownWidth,
        filter: "contains",
        optionLabel: 'Choose the task...',
        height: 400
    });
    var dropdownlist = dropDown.data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.open();
    KendoUiHelper.attachDropDownEventHandlers(dropDown);

});
function adjustDropDownWidth(e) {
    var listContainer = e.sender.list.closest(".k-list-container");
    listContainer.width(listContainer.width() + kendo.support.scrollbar());
}
```

I found out that this incorrect behavior occurs if only the length of the text inside of cell is larger then the width of the column, but I don't know what to do with this information.

Could you help me?